# How to use Yeoman to create a office content add-ins project

Tags: excel, office-js, yeoman, office-addins, yeoman-generator

Yeoman can create a office add-ins but can not create content add-ins

The document url:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Comment: What is your final goal? What exactly do you need to implement with office add-ins?

Comment: Hello , I want insert content to slide and then content can show diffent contents with edit mode and view mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an add-in manually, or just create an add-in with a manifest only. Yeoman doesn't include templates for content add-ins. See [Content Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins) in MSDN.

You can find the sample content add-in on GitHub - [Excel-Content-Add-in-Humongous-Insurance](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Content-Add-in-Humongous-Insurance).